# Use WhereIf for multiple condition in c#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, query-performance, iqueryable

Hi can someone help me how best we can use whereif in LINQ, here I have a code which works fine, but I want to convert this query with WhereIf.

```
    public async Task LoadQuery(IEnumerable<string> codes)
    {
        var query = _dBContext.QueryTable.Where(x => !x.InActive).AsQueryable();

        if (codes!= null && codes.Any())
            query = query.Where(x => codes.Contains(x.FirstCode) || query.Contains(x.SecondCode));
        else
            query = query.Where(x => !x.HasException.HasValue);

        var data = query.ToList();
    }
```

I have tried it with WhereIF ienumerable but not succeed. Here is the link which I followed. 
https://extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/whereif

Comment: can you try ``Where(x => codes!= null && codes.Any() ? (codes.Contains(x.FirstCode) || query.Contains(x.SecondCode)) : !x.HasException.HasValue)``, i think will work for linq to object, but i'm not sure for linq to entitie. ``query.Contains(x.SecondCode)`` will always true, why you add this condition.

Comment: for ``whereif`` in the example, is for ``linq to object``(ienumerable), you should use ``Expression`` instead of ``Func`` for ``Linq to entities``(Queryable).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
bool condition = codes!= null && codes.Any();
            var data  = _dBContext.QueryTable
                                       .WhereIf(condition, a=> codes.Contains(a.FirstCode) || codes.Contains(a.SecondCode))
                                       .WhereIf(!condition, a=> !a.HasException.HasValue && !a.InActive).ToList();
```

Comment: Extension method pocket mai daal diya baap apne :) Please share the WhereIf extension method as well. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`WhereIf` isn't really suitable for your case, for 2 reasons:

1. You're calling two different functions on your `if-else`, while `WhereIf` is built to accept a single function (`predicate`) to be executed if some `condition` is satisfied.
2. `WhereIf` is an extension method for `IEnumerable<TSource>`, while your'e trying to use it as an extension method for `IQueryable<TSource>`.

If you insist, you'd have to define an extension method for `IQueryable<TSource>`, and in doing so, just define it as `WhereIfElse`:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIfElse<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, bool> predicateIf, Func<TSource, bool> predicateElse)
    {
        if (condition)
            return source.Where(predicateIf).AsQueryable();
        else
            return source.Where(predicateElse).AsQueryable();
    } 
}
```

So, let's say that `query`'s type is `IQueryable<Item>` (replace `Item` with your actual type):

```
public async Task<List<Item>> LoadQuery(IEnumerable<string> codes)
{
    var query = _dBContext.QueryTable.Where(x => !x.InActive).AsQueryable();
    query = query.WhereIfElse(
         // condition
         codes != null && codes.Any(),  
         // predicateIf
         (Item x) => codes.Contains(x.FirstCode) || codes.Contains(x.SecondCode), 
         // predicateElse
         (Item x) => !x.HasException.HasValue                                    
    );
    var data = query.ToList();
    return data;
}
```

P.S. note I changed your return value, though there still isn't an `await`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool condition = codes!= null && codes.Any();
            var data  = _dBContext.QueryTable
                                       .WhereIf(condition, a=> codes.Contains(a.FirstCode) || codes.Contains(a.SecondCode))
                                       .WhereIf(!condition, a=> !a.HasException.HasValue && !a.InActive).ToList();
```

Add a Extension method for WhereIf, here we have extended Where for a type IEnumerable & IQuerable by passing a condition as first parameter and predicate as second parameter.

```
public static class LINQExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (condition)
            return source.Where(predicate);
        else
            return source;
    }

 public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (condition)
            return source.Where(predicate);
        else
            return source;
    }
}
```

Cheers :)